# jquery waypoints interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

i have this grid of li-items that i want to apply a class on with query waypoints. i want to apply the class individually so each item has it own fade in effect with different offset/interval. So i basically want each item to be its own waypoint. any one that have some code for this? would be great!

My html looks like this

```
<div class="item">text</div>
<div class="item">text</div>
<div class="item">text</div>
<div class="item">text</div>
<div class="item">text</div>
<div class="item">text</div>
```

And here are the js.

```
        $(".item").each(function(){
            var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                element: document.getElementByClass('.item'),
                handler: function(direction) {
                    if(direction == 'down') {
                        console.log(this.element.id + ' triggers at ' + this.triggerPoint)
                        $(this.element).addClass('fade');
                    }
                },
                offset: '90%'
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it. Here comes the solutions if anyone needs it.

```
            $(".item").each(function(index){
            $(this).attr('id','item_'+index);
            var waypoint = new Waypoint({
                element: document.getElementById('item_'+index),
                handler: function(direction) {
                    if(direction == 'down') {
                        console.log(this.element.id + ' triggers at ' + this.triggerPoint)
                        $(this.element).addClass('fade');
                    }
                },
                offset: '90%'
            });
        });
```